# How to run QNX Actionscript project on desktop Flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to run QNX Actionscript project on desktop Flash player, but when I run the swf, the player appears blank white view

I tried to set the QNX libraries "Merged in code", but the app doesn't run

Is there any way to run the project swf on flash player

Note: I am using Flash Builder 4.5

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the http://www.patrick-heinzelmann.de/labs/playbookdevicesimulation/  ?

And there is also:
http://renaun.com/blog/2011/02/workaround-for-ppschannel-error-when-running-qnx-playbook-specific-apis-on-the-desktop/